# embed Github gists in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, embed

How can I embed Github Gists to CKeditor?

Normally if i input this for example:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/ericbarnes/f8f533409af88cf35be520c101181384.js"></script>
```

will be ignored and removed.

Uptade:

script used........................................................

```
<script>
  var editor_config = {
    path_absolute : "/",
    selector: "textarea.my-editor",
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern codesample"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media | emoticons charmap | code codesample | forecolor backcolor",
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
      var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
      var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

      var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
      if (type == 'image') {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
      } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
      }

      tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file: '<?= route('elfinder.tinymce4') ?>',// use an absolute path!
        title: 'file manager',
        width: 900,
        height: 450,
        resizable: 'yes'
      }, {
        setUrl: function (url) {
          win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
        }
      });
    }
  };

  tinymce.init(editor_config);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your config option:

`config.extraAllowedContent = 'script[src]';`

More information is here - https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf

PS. But, please, note that allowing to submit script tags is not secure.

Comment: So what you suggest?

Comment: @mafortis if you asking about postscriptum -  i can't suggest anything because i don't know your goals and circumstances. Basically you allowing users to execute anything on your websites.

Comment: bro everywhere i use your code my editor becomes like ordinary textarea, i updated my question included my `js` would you please tell me where to put your code?

Comment: You are using CKEditor version 4, right ? Your config looks unfamiliar. But you can try to insert like this - `extraAllowedContent : "script[src]",` after `selector: "textarea.my-editor",` for example